# Exclude header row in Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking for this for quite some time now but I don't have enough understanding of the macro's to adjust and implement other solutions I found on here.

I am using Macro's to do a certain amount of actions on a sheet. The first row of the sheet contains headers, so I need to exclude the first row from some of the actions.

I will paste my code below, I understand this is not the best way to do this (would probably be better with an IF function) but this is how far I got up till now. Is there a way to simply exclude the entire header Row in the macros? Or just exclude T1 in these 3 steps where I populate column T?

```
Sub TASKDUESTATUS()
'
' TASKDUESTATUS Macro
'

'



'Filter Completed and In Progress
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:= _
        "=Completed", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=In Progress"
 'Fill Column T with 3
    Dim rX As Range
    Set rX = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("T:T")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rX.Value = "3"

'Filter Not Started
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:= _
        "Not Started"

 'Filter Date up till todays date with today INCLUDED
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<=" & Date

'Fill Column T with 2
    Dim rX2 As Range
    Set rX2 = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("T:T")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rX2.Value = "2"

'Filter Not Started
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:= _
        "Not Started"

'Filter date after todays date with today EXCLUDED
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=">" & Date

'Fill Column T with 1
    Dim rX3 As Range
    Set rX3 = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("T:T")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rX3.Value = "1"

'Add conditional formatting
    Columns("T:T").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .ReverseOrder = False
        .ShowIconOnly = False
        .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3TrafficLights1)
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercent
        .Value = 33
        .Operator = 7
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercent
        .Value = 67
        .Operator = 7
    End With

'Clear filters
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=21
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=19

End Sub
```

Comment: Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1), Range("T:T")).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)

Answer (score 0):

Add  `i = Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row` to find the lowest filled row in your data, 
and change the `("T:T")` to `("T1:T" & i)`.

This works at my end, do try and let me know.